# How to use Adjacency to transform (¬∨)∧(¬∨)∧(¬∨) into (¬∨∨)∧(¬∨∨¬)∧(¬∨)∧(¬∨)?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, boolean-algebra

I am going through the accepted [proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3092595/assistance-in-completing-the-proof-p-%E2%86%92-q%E2%88%A7q-%E2%86%92-r-is-equivalent-to-p-%E2%86%92-r%E2%88%A7) in this thread. There is a section of the proof that uses Adjacency to transform (¬∨)∧(¬∨)∧(¬∨)  into (¬∨∨)∧(¬∨∨¬)∧(¬∨)∧(¬∨).

It is not obvious to me how this was done.

Can someone show the complete steps of how this is achieved?

**Adjacency**

$$P = (P \lor Q) \land (P \lor \neg Q)$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The $\neg P \lor R$ gets transformed into $(\neg P \lor R \lor Q) \land (\neg P \lor R \lor \neg Q)$:

$$\neg P \lor R \overset{Adjacency}{=}$$

$$((\neg P \lor R) \lor Q) \land ((\neg P \lor R) \lor \neg Q) \overset{Association}{=}$$

$$((\neg P \lor R) \lor Q) \land ((\neg P \lor R) \lor \neg Q)$$

So in terms of Pattern Matching:

The '$P$' is $\neg P \lor R$, while the '$Q$' is $Q$

Comment: This answers my question. Writing to let you know I will accept your answer but I have to wait 8 minutes to do so. Would upvote but can't do that either. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @tree_traversal Don't worry about it. In fact, I shouldn't be gaining rep on a clarification on my own Answer! :)