# How to apply Absorption to (¬∨∨)∧(¬∨∨¬)∧(¬∨)∧(¬∨) to obtain (¬∨)∧(¬∨)?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, boolean-algebra

I am going through the accepted [proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3092595/assistance-in-completing-the-proof-p-%E2%86%92-q%E2%88%A7q-%E2%86%92-r-is-equivalent-to-p-%E2%86%92-r%E2%88%A7) in this thread.

There is a section that uses absorption for a final reduction into the desired result.

How do I use two applications of absorption to:

$(\neg P \lor R \lor Q) \land (\neg P \lor R \lor \neg Q) \land (\neg P \lor Q)  \land (\neg Q \lor R)$

to obtain:

$(\neg P \lor Q)  \land (\neg Q \lor R)$

Where Absorption is defined as:

**Absorption**

$$P \land (P \lor Q) = P$$

When I attempted it, I did a few applications of the distributive property, but my results did not pattern match in an obvious way to the absorption pattern. I would like to see how this is done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\neg P\vee Q=X,\neg Q\vee R=Y$. You thus want to simplify $(X\vee R)\wedge(\neg P\vee Y)\wedge X\wedge Y$. Since conjunction is commutative, it is equivalent to $(X\vee R)\wedge X\wedge(\neg P\vee Y)\wedge Y$. You'll need to apply the absorption law twice, once with the first and then with the last two terms:

$(X\vee R)\wedge X=X$ and $(\neg P\vee Y)\wedge Y=Y$. The final expression is $X\wedge Y$.

Comment: Can you elaborate what you mean by "middle two terms". From your post, I still don't see how to apply the absorption property twice to get the desired result.

Comment: Could you write out in full your steps? I don't see it based on what you wrote.

Comment: @tree_traversal Sorry, I was still in the process of editing the answer. You can check the answer now.

Comment: Thanks. This clarifies it for me!